# Elixir Agents visibility scope

Tags: elixir, agent

For example I create API Client for stackoverflow. I need to pass `access_token` to each endpoint.

I might do it like this:

```
StackClient.answers(access_token, params)
StackClient.badges(access_token, params)
```

But I don't wish to pass `access_token` to each request. And I improved logic by storing access token inside Agent.

```
def start(access_token) do
  Agent.start_link(fn -> %{access_token: access_token} end, name: __MODULE__)
end
```

Then I use ApiClient like this:

```
StackClient.start(access_token)
StackClient.answers(params)
StackClient.badges(params)
```

But this approach has a big issue, because Agent has global visibility scope for server. And two users might catch conflicts with access_token.

Guys! Is it possible to set Agent visibility within one http request?

Or might be another way to reduce number of arguments?

Comment: Why don't you want to pass `access_token` to each request? Is that a practical choice or just some _developer laziness_? ;) (No offence, we're all trying to be lazy)

Comment: @zwippie That looks a bit long :)

Answer (score 1):

From there, there are two ways forward.

`Agent.start_link` returns `{:ok, pid}`, with an identifier for the newly spawned process, so you could use that:

```
{:ok, pid} = StackClient.start(access_token)
StackClient.answers(pid, params)
StackClient.badges(pid, params)
```

Or you could give the process a different name:

```
def start(name, access_token) do
  Agent.start_link(fn -> %{access_token: access_token} end, name: name)
end
```

And use that when referring to the process:

```
{:ok, _} = StackClient.start(:my_stack_client, access_token)
StackClient.answers(:my_stack_client, params)
StackClient.badges(:my_stack_client, params)
```

Comment: So, these solutions don't resolve issue to reduce arguments =)

Anyway, we decided that adding access_token as param is not bad style